# How to pass Rails current_user to AngularJS factory API call?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, factory

In my Rails app I have users, and these can create posts that are associated to their account. I have a route, "/api/:user_id/submissions/:id(.:format)" => "submissions#usersubmission" which successfully will show the users post if the id matches with one associated to them.

What I'm trying to do now is display the users posts through AngularJS on the frontend. I'm not sure how to pass the :user_id to the API call. Here is my view:

```
<div id="submission-list-container">
                <ul id="indexSubmissions">
                        <li ng-repeat="submission in userSubmissions">
                        <a href="/submissions/{{submission.id}}"><h3 id="submissionh3">{{submission.title}} <small>{{submissionPreview(submission.content)}}</small></h3></a>
                        <h1>{{submission.user.email}}</h1>
                        <a id="edit_button" href="/submissions/{{submission.id}}/edit">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is my factory for this call:

```
BrainDB.factory('userSubmission', function($resource) {
var service = $resource('/api/:user_id/submissions/:id', {user_id: '@user_id'}, {id: '@id'} );

return service;
```

});

And the controller action that gets called:

```
def usersubmission
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @submissions = @user.submissions 
    @submission = @submissions.find(params[:id])
    render json: @submission 

end
```

The "BrainDB" Angular controller just .query()'s the userSubmission factory. In the 'userSubmission' factory, I'm not sure how to make the association to :user_id so that it successfully returns all the users' posts in JSON. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The user should never be sent from the client. You should **never** trust the client.

Your rails app should have a session, and you should store the current user somewhere in the session. (Session is a hash, if you are doing it manually just use a sensible key to store the current user's ID). You do it on logging in, and just retrieve it afterwards.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  attr_accessor :current_user

  before_filter :load_current_user

  # ...

  private

  def load_current_user
    self.current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

end
```

And in your controller:

```
def usersubmission
  @submissions = current_user.submissions 
  @submission = @submissions.find(params[:id])
  render json: @submission 
end
```

If you use Devise or similar it's much easier anyway, as these kind of libraries already inject a `current_user` (or similarly named method) in the controllers.

Comment: Is there anything I need to modify in the devise sessions controller? Mine just looks like "class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController" but it would inherit their logic. I made the changes you suggested and it throws the error "Couldn't find User without an ID" on the load_current_user action.

Comment: When I pass "self.current_user = User.find(2)" it brings up my account successfully, so for some reason User.find(session[:user_id]) isn't passing an id.

Comment: So you use devise. Devise already injects `current_user` in all your controllers and views, no need to define anything by yourself. Just use what Devise provides.

Comment: @rewritten, I'm using devise. If I follow your method it ends up showing the json itself on localhost:3000 instead of my homepage. What should I do? Here is my code: before_action: load_current_user; private ;def load_current_user;
    if signed_in?;
      (at)currentuser = current_user;
      render json: (at)currentuser;
    end;
  end

Comment: @SzilardMagyar why on earth would you call `render` in a before_action ?

Comment: @rewritten, thanks for the answer. I also realized it after writing the comment, but still don't know what's the best way to pass the current_user to js. I mean to pure js not to js.erb. At the moment, I'm using data-currentuser = "<%= current_user.id %>" on body tag.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar that's a perfectly fine way. Also you can embed a small script that sets some global or attribute: `<script> window.globalState || (window.globalState = {}); window.globalState.currentUserId = <%= j current_user.id %>;</script>`.

Comment: @rewritten, sry but I'm a beginner and don't totally get it. Could you elaborate what extra I will have if I embed this one besides the data-currentuser? Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to parse it from data if you already assign it to a variable. Nothing more.